# Safari extension builded with Xcode, disappears from Safari after rebuild

Tags: xcode, macos, safari, safari-extension

I'm trying to build a Safari extension using Xcode, using this manual: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/building_a_safari_app_extension

The first time it builds fine and actually works, however if I want to rebuild it after changes, the extension disappears from Safari.

Here're Few parameters I'm using:

- Xcode app is build on Cacoa App template
- App contains a Safari Extension target
- Safari Allowed Unsigned Extension is checked

Console is throwing the following errors:

- `plug-in <private> pre-screen sees activating state`
- `Hub connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named ext.demo.Extension" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named ext.demo.Extension}`
- `PlugInKit error in beginUsing: with plugin identifier: <private>, killing plugin`

I guess I am missing something important here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a `Clean Build Folder` under the `Product` menu - or - `Shift-Command-K` before you run it again, and you should be good to go!

Comment: I seem to have to `shift-command-k` every time before the rebuild. Is there any way to fix it permanently?